# How to loops on field names of a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reflection

I have got a class which contains more then 160 fields. i need the name of fields (not value) in an array.
i need help to get loop through names for field or get list of field names in a array so that i can loop over it and use it in code. i am using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

Try this example from
http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection-field

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get all the fields

```
Type type = typeof(YourType); 
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
```

then you can use `Name` property of `FieldInfo` to get name of your field